# Mule testing best practices and functional vs unit

Tags: mule

I am looking for some guidance on what are the best practices for testing Mule applications.

For example, i am separating my logic into multiple private flows and using flow-refs to tie them together.

I am then using Munit to mock out the flow-refs so flows are tested in isolation.

This to me seems like unit testing and treats flows as methods etc.

Is this a valid approach to testing Mule application?

Should I also be writing functional tests that test these all working together without and mocked flows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is correct!

You can compartmentalise your code as much as it actually make sense, i.e. using flows and sub-flows mainly because it's common sense. T
hen again you shouldn't try to split everything into sub-flows just because.

Regarding unit vs functional, I don't think it should be a "Vs". They complement each other. You should always try to do unit testing and functional/integration tests.

Finally there are different degrees of test you could have.
You could mock all the flow-ref, then you could just mock only calls to external endpoints, or not mock anything at all do an end to end integration and use the before/after test and before/after suite of Munit to do the compensation transactions of your integration test.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using vm connector, then you will test a specific piece of your flow.