# What to test and when?

Tags: unit-testing, mule, integration-testing

I am building mule applications that synchronize data between different systems, services and APIs.

My Mule application is roughly as follows:

1. Poll a HTTP endpoint to get some user information
2. Enrich message with a user id from a user service
3. Transform the data for another service
4. Call the other service with the transformed data.

What should I be testing here,

For example I am testing the data transformation which I consider Unit testing. 
I am testing that if a (stubbed) response is returned from the user service the value is correctly enriched using my expression. I guess this would be functional testing?

But should I be testing the poll gets started? That each endpoint gets called? Would this be integration testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is to make sure I define the "units" of my software in a way that allows me to test only what matters about my application, and not the aspects that might change if I need to refactor.  In Mule ESB applications, this sometimes leaves me with very few unit tests that look similar to those I would write in a java program.  Most of my unit tests inherit from FunctionalTestCase, and involve some number of in-process test doubles for the real systems I need to integrate.

I have tried using Munit to accomplish this, but there are a few design decisions that make this style of testing difficult.  Therefore my unit test usually inherit from FunctionalTestCase.

For your application, I might create tests as follows:

1. Make sure the first HTTP endpoint is polled correctly (HTTP GET with some path information and query parameters I would assume)
2. Given a certain ID returned from the user service, make sure the target service is called correctly with the transformed message
3. If the transformation logic is complex, I might add several tests that explore the different edge cases to be sure my transformation is working properly
4. Many times web services require certain headers or authorization tokens, so I often create several tests making sure these are in place

Note that I don't explicitly test that my message gets "enriched" or "transformed" mid-flow, because those steps are only a means to an end.  Should you decide down the road to do the transformation in two steps, or use XSLT instead of java, these tests will not need to be changed.

To make the in-process test doubles for your HTTP services, take a look at [sham-http](https://github.com/shamsoftware/sham-http).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Also, how do you name you test classes and methods? As a test method covers quite a lot of functionality and doesn't really follow the same way you'd test a Java method as you said.

Comment: Some examples might be validUser_shouldBePostedToAccountsService() or expiredUser_shouldBeDeletedFromAccountsService()  for the transformation type tests.  Others look like accountService_shouldReceiveAuthorizationHeader() and connectionRefusedToAccountService_shouldRetryThreeTimes()

Answer (score 0):

As far as testing Mule code I would recommend three set so f testcases.

1. Unit Tests.
   Testing all the code independently for their correctness.
2. Functional Testing.
   Tesitng the mule flows and sub-flows to make sure the flows are working as expected. For this FunctionalTests the org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase can be used. All the calls to external services and applications should be stubbed in this inorder to avoid dependency on external factors during testing.
3. Integration Testing.
   Testing the integration with all the external services and applications. These testcases are almost to similar to Mule functional testcases except that calls are actually made to external integrating services.

By covering all these three categories of the testcases we can be assured taht the Mule service is fully functional.

What to be tested is always the requirement and the comfort of each individual project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with has been said here, but just a comment. 
In what regards unit test there are two things to consider. First your custom java code which should always be unit tested. But you can also do unit test of your Mule application. 
For that Mule offers [Munit](https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/wiki). 
Munit is a testing framework that among other things allows you to create mocks of message processors as well as do verifications of the call to the message processors.

Munit is in part based on `org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase` so you can do the same but you'll have more functionality with Munit.

Also please check this other link that may help 
[Mule testing best practices and functional vs unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277773/mule-testing-best-practices-and-functional-vs-unit/28278050#28278050)

Cheers!